# Accessing a particular element in a list

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and wanted to access specific elements of the list.For eg-

```
L=[name,age,height,weight,gender]
```

How can I access age and height from this list as I want to compare them with some given values???

Answer (score 0):

A list is not intended to be used as a record. Anyway, just use unification

```
L = [Name,Age,Height,Weight,Gender],
( Gender == male -> ... ; ... )
```

Comment: Actually I want to implement something like this-
`L=['Peter',21,5.9,70,'male'].`
Then when the user enters suppose age=22,I want to check age with 2nd element of my list L.Is this possible??

Comment: What make you think it's not *possible* ? It's just not *convenient* to use a list for structured information, because it's difficult to remember the exact position of elements...

Comment: Suppose I know the position,then how can I do it?Suppose I want to access 2nd position.

Comment: SWI-Prolog has nth1/3 and nth0/3, other Prolog(s) have nth/3... Anyway, `nth1(2,L,Age)` will do